# Excel VBA print to specific printer tray

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel (2007) VBA how do I print the worksheet to a specific printer tray? This will just print to the default tray on the printer:

```
ws.PrintOut ActivePrinter:="\\print_server\printer_name"
```

Comment: Creating different printers seems to be the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft offers one [ugly solution](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;213815&Product=vba) to this problem; using `SendKeys` to manually choose the correct tray from the print settings dialog box.

Another option may be to set up additional printers in Windows, where each printer is actually linked to a different tray on the same printer. You could then select the appropriate tray in VBA. [This article](http://excel.tips.net/Pages/T002213_Specifying_a_Paper_Tray_in_a_Macro.html) has the details.

Or, if your printer happens to have a different size of paper in the tray you want to print to, you can set (for example):

```
ws.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
```

And the printer will automatically select the correct tray. I just tried this out on my printer here, and it forced the sheet to print on the manual tray, because I don't actually have a legal size paper tray.